# too much recursion when call function(params) with timeout

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

i'm having a problem when recursion function.i'm get the error in firebug

> too much recursion

this is my javascript code:

```
var contentPc = "list";
waitForBody(contentPc);
function waitForBody(id){
    var ele = document.getElementById(id);
    if(!ele){
        window.setTimeout(waitForBody(contentPc), 100);
    }
    else{
        //something function
    }
}
```

how i can fix this? thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Presumably, you don't have an `id="list"` element in your DOM. That would mean that your initial `waitForBody` call would end up here:

```
window.setTimeout(waitForBody(contentPc), 100);
```

and that will call `waitForBody(contentPc)` while building the argument list for `setTimeout`. And then you end up back at the `setTimeout` call again but one more stack level deep. I think you mean to say this:

```
window.setTimeout(function() { waitForBody(contentPc) }, 100);
```

so that the next `waitForBody` call is delayed a little bit.

Comment: Nice to see my guess at JS syntax was correct - but my answer is pointless given yours :)